# proper way to support(write) a inputstream for large content

Tags: java, scala, inputstream

I have this scenario where I need to create an method which return an `InputStream` to caller, say:

```
def getStream(key): (contentLength, content: InputStream)
```

The goal is to return a very large content binary(GBs) through the content `InputStream`.

The logic inside this method, is supposed to be something like:

```
val os = new PipedOutputStream()
val is = new PipedInputStream(os)

for (file <- smallfiles) // a sequence of small files
  os.write(file)
```

When the total size is big, say 500GB, will this for loop cause memory issues etc? If so, what is the right way to handle such situation?

Comment: I don't understand. The `content` `InputStream` is something `getStream` must read from - it cannot write to it or "return" data through it.

Comment: I think it is not a problem. You read first file byte by byte (use BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream) and when you finished you close them and start read second file. You have always open only one input file - output file is on disk - not in memory.